# Importing database structures in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

As I said many times I'm new in Symfony2 framework and I ask about it a lot. Here is my new problem. I'm trying to import my mysql database into my symfony application. I'm following this tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-web-app-with-symfony-2-bootstrapping/

This is the code that I run;

```
php app\console doctrine:mapping:import
```

This is the error that I get;

```
[DoctrineORMMappingMappingException] Property "bookid" in "BookHeadline" was already     declared, but it must be declared only once
```

In the link there is a comment about this issue and it says remove the FK 'bookid'. I tried it but even the sql query did not work. Also [this](https://github.com/phpmasterdotcom/TaylorRen-SymfonyApp_01/blob/master/misc/rsywx.sql) is the sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you paste the table structure for that entity?

Also take a look at [Symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) about importing your database